# Gta 5 hobbies & pastimes

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm at 98.3% completion in the game: I've done 69 missions, 20/20 of the strangers & freaks, 14/14 of the random events. Now I already know the last one I have to so for the knife flights and I'll have completed the miscellaneous 16/16. Now I have 40/42 hobbies & pastimes and I cannot figure out the last 2. I've gone back and tried doing them all again and still the same results. 40/42. I can't gain access to the social rock club. I don't have my Xbox360 connected to the internet. So is there any other way I can check what I have done? I've been playing the game for months stuck on 98.3%

Answer (score 2):

Below are a list of Hobbies & Pastimes activities. Please note this includes the next-gen activities too so just skip the ones that aren't available to you.

> **List of Hobbies and Pastimes:**
>
> 1. Stunt Plane Time Trials (Special & Collector's Edition only)
> 2. Shooting Range: Hand Guns (win 3 medals)
> 3. Shooting Range: Submachine Guns (win 3 medals)
> 4. Shooting Range: Assault Rifles (win 3 medals)
> 5. Shooting Range: Shotguns (win 3 medals)
> 6. Shooting Range: Light Machine Guns (win 3 medals)
> 7. Shooting Range: Heavy (win 3 medals)
> 8. Street Race: South Los Santos (win a medal)
> 9. Street Race: City Circuit (win a medal)
> 10. Street Race: Airport (win a medal)
> 11. Street Race: Freeway (win a medal)
> 12. Street Race: Vespucci Canals (win a medal)
> 13. Win at Tennis
> 14. Play 9 holes of Golf & finish even or below par
> 15. Win at Darts
> 16. Get a private dance at the Strip Club
> 17. Triathlon 1: Vespucci Canals (win a medal)
> 18. Triathlon 2: Alamo Sea (win a medal)
> 19. Triathlon 3: Coyote Cross Country (win a medal)
> 20. Offroad Race 1: Canyon Cliffs (win a medal)
> 21. Offroad Race 2: Ridge Run (win a medal)
> 22. Offroad Race 3: Mineward Spiral (win a medal)
> 23. Offroad Race 4: Valley Trail (win a medal)
> 24. Offroad Race 5: Lakeside Splash (win a medal)
> 25. Offroad Race 6: Eco Friendly (win a medal)
> 26. Bail Bonds - Quarry
> 27. Bail Bonds - Farm
> 28. Bail Bonds - Mountain
> 29. Bail Bonds - Hobo
> 30. Arms Traffic Air 1
> 31. Arms Traffic Air 2
> 32. Arms Traffic Air 3
> 33. Arms Traffic Air 4
> 34. Arms Traffic Air 5
> 35. Arms Traffic Ground 1
> 36. Arms Traffic Ground 2
> 37. Arms Traffic Ground 3
> 38. Arms Traffic Ground 4
> 39. Arms Traffic Ground 5
> 40. Hunting
> 41. Flight School: Training Take Off (win a medal)
> 42. Flight School: Runway Landing (win a medal)
> 43. Flight School: Inverted Flight (win a medal)
> 44. Flight School: Knife Flight (win a medal)
> 45. Flight School: Flat Hatting (win a medal)
> 46. Flight School: Touch Down (win a medal)
> 47. Flight School: Loop the loop (win a medal)
> 48. Flight School: Helicopter Course (win a medal)
> 49. Flight School: Helicopter Speed Run (win a medal)
> 50. Flight School: Skydiving (win a medal)
> 51. Flight School: Drop Zone (win a medal)
> 52. Flight School: Earn Your Wings (win a medal)
> 53. Sea Race: East Coast (win a medal)
> 54. Sea Race: North East Coast (win a medal)
> 55. Sea Race: Raton Canyon (win a medal)
> 56. Sea Race: Los Santos (win a medal)
> 57. Perform Yoga
> 58. Parachuting: Complete all Base Jumps
> 59. Parachuting: Complete all Heli Jumps
> 60. Wildlife Photography
> 61. Stock Car Races